# Why do we separately cast to "float" in an integer division?

Tags: c, variables

For example:

```
int number1 = 1, number2= 2;
float variable = (float)number1/(float)number2;
```

Instead of this, Why can't we use "float" only once? For example:

```
int number1 = 1, number2= 2;
float variable = (float)(number1/number2);
```

Comment: Because integer division truncates. Use `printf` to display the results from both calculations, and you'll find that the first result is `0.5` and the second result is `0.0`, since `1/2` truncates to `0`.

Comment: Well, `number1/number2` is integer division. In fact, the `(float)` in the second example makes no difference.

Comment: Because the divison operation would have truncated the decimal places before the conversion to float.

Comment: The evaluation of a subexpression generally is not affected by the context in which it appears. Since `number1` and `number2` are both of type `int`, `(number1/number2)` is evaluated using `int`-by-`int` division. Casting the result to `float` doesn't change that.

Comment: Very related: [c - Why did my float get truncated? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097935/why-did-my-float-get-truncated)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The objective is to avoid the truncation that comes with integer division. This requires that *at least one* of the operands of the division be a floating point number. Thus you only need one cast to `float`, but in the right place. For example,

```
float variable = number1/(float)number2; // denominator is float
```

or

```
float variable = ((float)number1)/number2; // numerator is float
```

Note that in the second example, one extra set of parentheses has been added for clarity, but due to precedence rules, it is the same as

```
float variable = (float)number1/number2; // numerator is float, same as above
```

Also note that in your second example,

```
float variable = (float)(number1/number2);
```

the cast to `float` is applied *after* the integer division, so this does not avoid truncation. Since the result of the expression is assigned to a `float` anyway, it is the exact of

```
float variable = number1/number2;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write either expression, but you get different results.

With `float variable = (float)(number1 / number2);` the value in `variable` is 0, because the division is done as integer division, and 1/2 is 0, and the result is converted.

With `float variable = (float)number1 / (float)number2;`, the value in `variable` is 0.5, because the division is done as floating point division.

Either one of the casts in `float variable = (float)number1 / (float)number2;` can be omitted and the result is the same; the other operand is converted from `int` to `float` before the division occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Since `number1` and `number2` are `int`s, the division performed will be integral division. Thus, `number1/number2` will evaluate to the `int` 0. To do floating point arithmetic instead, you need to cast them. Note that simply casting one will suffice, since the other one will be implicitly promoted. So, you can just say `((float)number1)/number2`.

Answer (score 0):

In the First case,

1/2 results 0

In the second case, you can use float once, but it has to be applied with one of the numbers before division

1.0/2.0  or 1.0/2 or  1/2.0  results 0.5