# Why did my float get truncated?

Tags: c, casting

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     float c =8/5;
     printf("The Result: %f", c);
     return 0;
 }
```

The answer is `1.000000`.  Why isn't it `1.600000`?

Comment: There is no type casting involved. Would be a good idea to change the title.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I disagree; While the question is badly researched, it is not about he difference between integer and rounded floating point division, but why an integer division does not yield a float result.

Comment: While the title is better now, you seem to have missed the point `8 / 5` is **not** a float(ing point) expression, but an integer. None of the operands are floating point values.

Comment: float c is getting its result from a cast of an int result of (8/5)  which is (obviously) 1.

Comment: @milevyo: There is no cast! A cast is an expiclt conversion, e.g. `(float)8`. This is a(n implicit) converversion from `int` to `float`. (I sometimes wish Pascal - or better Modula-2 - had won the game).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is interpreting your `8/5` input as integers. With integers, C truncates it down to 1.

Change your code to `8.0/5.0`. That way it knows you're working with real numbers, and it will store the result you're looking for.

Comment: Just to clarify: The compiler **has to** "interpret" the expression as integers, because the constants _are_ integers. More exactly, they have  type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
8/5
```

is an all `int` expression. So, it evaluates to `(int )1`

The automatic conversion to `float` happens in the assignment.

If you convert to float before the divide, you will get the answer you seek:

```
(float )8/5
```

or just

```
8.0/5
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't specify what data types you use (for example, in your code you use the integer constants `8` and `5`) C uses the smallest reasonable type.  In your case, it assigned `8` and `5` the integer type, and because both operands to the division expression were integers, C produced an integer result.  Integers don't have decimal points or fractional parts, so C truncates the result.  This throws away the remainder of the division operation leaving you with 1 instead of 1.6.

Notice this happens even though you store the result in a float.  This is because the expression is evaluated using integer types, then the result is stored as is.

There are at least two ways to fix this:

**Cast the part of the expression to a double type or other type that can store fractional parts:**

Here `8` is cast to the `double` type, so C will perform float division with the operands.  Note that if you cast `(8 / 5)`, integer division will be performed before the cast.

```
foo = (double) 8 / 5
```

**Use a double as one of the operands:**

```
foo = 8.0/5
```

Comment: C doesn't do floor division; pre-C99, it's either floor or truncate towards zero, implementation defined, in C99 and later it's strictly truncate towards zero, not floor. For positive results it's the same thing (both round down), but for negative results floor division rounds down, truncate towards zero rounds up.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good to know, I'll edit that in.

Comment: It's a little misleading to say that you're casting the expression in the first example. The cast operator has precedence over the division, so you're actually casting 8 to a float. If you wrote `(float)(8/5)`, you'd still get 1.

Comment: @zneak Good catch.  I'll add that as well.

Comment: C does not "guess" what types you use, but this is very well specified by the standard. Basically, for an integer constant, it uses the "smallest" possible, starting with `int` (not `char`!). For that the term "rank" is used in the standard.

Comment: @Olaf You're right, I was dumbing it down a little.  The answer is now more accurate.

Comment: You use some uncommon (at best) or very missleading terms in your answer. For instance: what do you mean with "decimals"? an _integer constant_ like `101` is very well a decimal number (`0101` is octal for example). Also note that `8.0` is not a `float`, but a `double`. A `float` constant would be `8.0f`.

Comment: Sorry to tell you, it is still incorrect. FYI: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: @Olaf Which part are you referring to as incorrect?  How C decides which type to use when evaluating expressions with magic numbers?  I'm looking at the standard right now but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking for...

Comment: 1) The term "magic numbers" is missplaced here. `8` and `5` are _integer constants_ according to the standard, another term is _integer literal_ (to differentiate from symbolic constants of interger type - which C does not support). 2) As there are some "flaws" in your text, I'd recommend to get comfortable with the terminology in the standard in general. That greatly imploves readbility/understandability (& some other -abilities) and constistency with the standard. 3) For this, you might start with the conversions section. Tough reading for a beginner, but worth, if you want to learn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102056/discussion-between-brandaemon-and-olaf).

Comment: Sorry, no time. Just to clarify: That honestly was meant as friendly help,not an offence. Everyone has to learn.

Comment: I just suggested chat because SO comments are getting mad at me.  I really appreciate the help and I did learn a lot.  Thanks!