# Why does 5/2 results in '2' even when I use a float?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, precision, division

I entered the following code (and had no compiling problems or anything):

```
float y = 5/2;
printf("%f\n", y);
```

The output was simply:  `2.00000`

My math isn't wrong is it? Or am I wrong on the / operator? It means divide doesn't it? And 5/2 should equal 2.5?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because the *result* is `float`. But the operands and hence the operation itself is integer.

Comment: [Related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674295/why-do-we-separately-cast-to-float-in-an-integer-division).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`5` is an `int` and `2` is an `int`. Therefore, `5/2` will use integer division. If you replace `5` with `5.0f` (or `2` with `2.0f`), making one of the `int`s a `float`, you will get floating point division and get the `2.5` you expect. You can also achieve the same effect by explicitly casting either the numerator or denominator (e.g. `((float) 5) / 2`).

Comment: `5.` or `2.` will do.

Comment: @alk: I just like to have the zeros there - they serve no real purpose, but with my decaying eyesight, I often miss `.` by itself but I haven't yet missed a `.0`.

Comment: I'd then propose to use `.00`, as you most likely have two eyes. ;-)

Comment: @alk  Thank you both! :D

Answer (score 3):

> Why does 5/2 results in '2' even when I use a float?

Because you do **not** "*use `float`*". `5/2` is an integer division. Only its result (`2`) gets implicitly converted to a `float` to become a `2.` (mind the dot).

Answer (score 0):

You should do proper type-casting .

```
float y = (float) 5/2
```

Program will treat the numbers as `int`.
It is dividing two `int`s and writing this to `float`. Hence, answer is 2.0

You must type cast